# R: optimize timeseries to minimize "integral"

Tags: time-series, programming, optimization

What I am looking to do is:

for a given time-series $P_t$ (which will be constructed from different timeseries itself):

$P_t$ = $\beta_1$*$I_t^1$+$\beta_2$*$I_t^2$+$\beta_3$$I_t^3$ $\qquad$ ($I_t^i$ are $i$ number of time-series)

I want to

$min$$\sum_t^T|$$P_t$-$\bar{P}$| where $\bar{P}$ = **1** (centered around 1)

esentially choosing the ***$\beta$s*** such that |$P_t$-$\bar{P}$| is minimized over *[ t,T ]*.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far and where the exact problem is?

Comment: Are you sure you want to minimise the differences? Or rather the absolute differences?

Comment: :+1:  thanks Enrico! that is exactly what I meant

Comment: Never answer an "or-question" with "yes" ;-)

Comment: Vonjd, I am sorry you couldn’t gather from context that I indeed meant to minimize the absolute differences (also changed it in the initial question)

Answer (score 3):

A simple, though somewhat inflexible, way would be to
regress $\bar{P}$ on the $I$ series only (no constant). This will minimise
squared differences instead of absolute ones, though.

R example; I start with creating random data:

```
nobs <- 250  ## length of series
ns <- 3      ## number of I series

P <- c(1, cumprod(1 + rnorm(nobs, sd = 0.01)))
M <- sum(range(P))/2  ## midpoint of range
I <- array(rnorm((nobs)*ns, sd = 0.01),
           dim = c(nobs, ns))
I <- apply(I, 2, function(x) cumprod(1+x))
I <- rbind(1, I)

plot(P, ylim = range(P, I), type = "l",
     col = "darkgreen", lwd = 2)
abline(h = M)
for (i in 1:ns)
    lines(I[,i], col = grey(0.7))

## regression
res1 <- lm(rep(M, nrow(I)) ~ -1 + I)
lines(I %*% coef(res1),
      col = "blue", lwd = 2,
      type = "l")
```

An alternative way would be to use a generic solver.
Here is an example with Differential Evolution, as
implemented in the R package [`NMOF`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=NMOF), which I maintain.

```
## Differential Evolution
library("NMOF")
diff_mean <- function(b, M, I)
    sum(abs(M - I %*% b))

res2 <- DEopt(diff_mean,
              list(min = rep(-1, ns),
                   max = rep(1, ns)),
              M = M, I = I)

lines(I %*% res2$xbest, 
      col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

The advantage of such a solver is that it is much more
flexible: you may use another function to measure the
similarity of the series, or add constraints.

Comment: Didn't know the package, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: I just changed the question slightly... It should be enough to make $\bar{P}$ a constant. However, I am unsure how to apply DEopt for a dataframe (of multiple vectors) in order to extract my betas.

Comment: It is unfortunate that you changed your question, as now my code
example does not match it any more. But anyway: what do you mean by
multiple vectors? In the example, `I` is already a matrix; simply
overwrite `M` with your constant series.

Comment: I did get the DEopt working now. However I am getting more than one solution for xbest across multiple runs even though I do think there should be one definitive solution. I already did change the min&max values.

Comment: DE is a stochastic method, so its solutions are, in a sense, random. However, with more iterations, this randomness should decrease and eventually disappear. So, try with an increased number of steps (`nG` in `DEopt`). See also the discussion in section 3 of https://ssrn.com/abstract=1140655

Comment: learning by doing ;-) : sorry about that but my inital question was correct (P bar needs to be the average between the high and the low of the constructed timeseries [which depends on the betas itself]), so I changed it back...
The problem is though that Pbar depends on P which in turn depends on the betas. Is that already accounted for in the above code?

Comment: No, you would need to write it into the objective function (i.e. compute `M` in the objective function). You need to be careful not to end up with a trivial solution (all betas equal to zero). So perhaps you need constraints on the betas as well.

Answer (score 0):

I is a t x i matrix. Each vector in I is weighted by a beta each such that diff_mean is minimized. I will center the process around 1 (M=1) and square the differences to "punish" higher deviations (and prevent netting of errors) from M:

```
    #Optimization
library("NMOF")
ns=dim(df)[2]
M=1
diff_mean <- function(b, M, df)
  sum((10000*(M-(df%*%b)))^2)
res <- DEopt(diff_mean,
             list(nG = 100000,
                  min = rep(-100, ns),
                  max = rep(100, ns)),
             M = M, df = df)

output=res$xbest
solution=output/output[1]
```

Bingo!